# Creating a List to Populate a Combo Box with Linq to SQL Query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, combobox, sortedlist

Problem: I have a simple cboBox call PhoneTypes. I want its datasource to be ideally a sortedList generated from a linq to sql query which pulls data from a tblPhonetypes.
I also want the combo box to be bound.

```
class PhoneType 
{
    int _idxPhoneType;
    string _charPhoneType;
    public PhoneType(int idxPhoneType, string charPhoneType)
    {
        this.idxPhoneType = idxPhoneType;
        this.charPhoneType = charPhoneType;
    }
    public int idxPhoneType { get; set; }
    public string charPhoneType { get; set; }
   .....//other properties..such as timestamp...etc
}
```

In the Main window I have:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public Window mainWindow;    
    public PhoneType selectedPhoneType { get; set; }

// do we need to have a getter/setter on a list to data bind to??  
//       public List<PhoneType> phonetypelist {get;set;)
// not sure if we need an implementation of data context here !
// DocITDatabaseEntities ctx = new DocITDatabaseEntities();

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DocITDatabaseEntities ctx = new DocITDatabaseEntities();
        DataContext = this;
        cboPtPhoneType.ItemsSource = phonetypelist;
        cboPtPhoneType.DataContext = // todo;           
    }
    private SortedList(int,string) phonelist()
    {
        DocITDatabaseEntities ctx = new DocITDatabaseEntities();
        List<PhoneType> lstphones = from p in ctx.tblPhoneTypes
                                    orderby p.charPhoneType
                                    select p;
        // To do...create the list and pass it to the combo box as the       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you now want to have `lstphones` bound to a ComboBox named `cboPhoneType` right?

So, make sure the list is accessible from your DataContext, to as of now, lstphones only exists within the scope of `phonelist()`. You need to make it a property of your MainWindow class, assign the list inside your phonelist() method and make sure to raise INotifyPropertyChanged event in the "set" of your list.

Then, the last thing you need to do in your XAML is :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding yourList}" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedPhoneType}" />
```

If I may, you should look at the MVVM Pattern it will greatly help you in WPF